# Extract content between two sets of tags

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some content and put it in tabular format on Excel. One column would be countries, the second column would be the measures they're implementing against the coronavirus. Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<strong>AUSTRALIA</strong> - published 11.02.2020<br />
1. Passengers who have transited through or have been in China (People's Rep.) on or after 1 February 2020, will not be allowed to transit or enter Australia.<br />
- This does not apply to nationals of Australia. They will be required to self-isolate for a period of 14 days from their arrival into Australia.<br />
- This does not apply to permanent residents of Australia and their immediate family members. They will be required to self-isolate for a period of 14 days from their arrival into Australia.<br />
- This does not apply to airline crew.<br />
2. Nationals of Australia who have transited through or have been in China (People's Rep.) on or after 1 February 2020 will be required to self-isolate for a period of 14 days from their arrival into Australia.<br />
3. Permanent residents of Australia and their immediate family members who have transited through or have been in China (People's Rep.) on or after the 1 February 2020 will be required to self-isolate for a period of 14 days from their arrival into Australia.<br />
<br />
<strong>AZERBAIJAN</strong> - published 06.02.2020
```

So there is no real structure to speak of. However I'd like to be able to extract the list of countries as one column (that's easy since they're between *strong* tags). But I would like the other column to be the corresponding text for each country. That's harder since there is nothing to isolate this. The only thing that I can think of is to ask VBA to loop between two sets of *strong* tags and extract this content as the second column. I'm not sure how to do this though. The code I've found so far allows me to extract the list of countries and not much else:

```
Sub Test()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

    Set HTMLAs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("strong")

    For Each HTMLA In HTMLAs

    Debug.Print HTMLA.innerText
    If HTMLA.getAttribute("href") = "http://x-rates.com/table/" And HTMLA.getAttribute("rel") = "ratestable" Then
        HTMLA.Click
'I don't understand why, but the previous line of code is essential to making this work. Otherwise I only get the first country
        Exit For
        End If

Next HTMLA

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the comments in the macro. Feel free to order the text in another way or get the message date out of the string or what ever you want:

**Edit 2:** I deleted the first edit because I pointed out errors in the macro. But I have fixed them now and have replaced the macro code with this edit

**Edit 3:** I replaced the second macro with the one which works now

```
Sub ExtractCoronaVirusCountryInfos()

  'To get the clear text for each country we must restruct the html code of parts of the page
  'It's necessary to delete some tags (p and span) and place some new tags (div and p)
  'To manipulate the html code like we need it we use tools of the dom (document object model)
  'and tools to make string operations on the html code

  Dim url As String
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim nodeTextContainer As Object
  Dim nodeAllP As Object
  Dim nodeOneP As Object
  Dim nodeNewBody As Object
  Dim nodeAllDiv As Object
  Dim nodeOneDiv As Object
  Dim htmlString As String
  Dim tableRow As Long
  Dim tableColumn As Long
  Dim countryName As String
  Dim infoDate As String
  Dim infoText As String
  Dim p As Long
  Dim openingArrowBracketIndex As Long
  Dim closingArrowBracketIndex As Long
  Dim openingRealBrTagComment As Long
  Dim closingRealBrTagComment As Long
  Dim openingRealBrTagStyle As Long
  Dim closingRealBrTagStyle As Long

  tableRow = 2
  tableColumn = 1
  url = "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate url
  Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  'Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

  'Get the text container
  Set nodeTextContainer = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("middle")(0)
  '
  'Get all p-tags
  'They contain the text we want
  Set nodeAllP = nodeTextContainer.getElementsByTagName("p")
  '
  'Kick the p tags (only the opening and closing strings)
  'and concatinate the results of this operation
  'We can do this very easy by getting the innerhtml
  For Each nodeOneP In nodeAllP
    htmlString = htmlString & nodeOneP.innerhtml
  Next nodeOneP

  'Now we want to kick the span tags. But we can't do that in the same way
  'like with the p tags because there are nested span tags in the document
  'Let's see what's the problem with nested tags
  '
  'HTML code example with two nested span tags:
  '<span>
  '  <span>
  '    Data to show
  '  </span>
  '</span
  '
  'VBA code to build a node collection:
  'Set nodeAllSpan = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
  '
  'Now there are two elements in the node collection:
  'nodeAllSpan(0) = <span><span>Data to show</span></span>
  'nodeAllSpan(1) = <span>Data to show</span>
  '
  'The Text we want is doubled!
  'If we take the innertext of the whole collection we get this:
  'Data to showData to show
  '
  'That is realy not our goal. Thats the reason we use string operations to delete
  'all span tags. For the closing parts </span> it's easy with replace. The opening
  'parts are unknown because they can have style information, attributes and even
  'more. So we must search first for '<span'. Than for '>' after the before found
  'position in string. Then we can delete the tag and go on for the next one
  '
  'First we replace the closing parts of all span tags with an empty string
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "</span>", "")
  '
  'With the following part of the macro we delete the opening parts of all span tags
  'We must search the whole string after each manipulation again so we need a loop
  'until there is no more span tag
  Do
    openingArrowBracketIndex = InStr(1, htmlString, "<span")
    closingArrowBracketIndex = InStr(openingArrowBracketIndex + 1, htmlString, ">")
    If openingArrowBracketIndex > 1 Then
      openingArrowBracketIndex = openingArrowBracketIndex - 1
    End If
    htmlString = Left(htmlString, openingArrowBracketIndex) & Mid(htmlString, closingArrowBracketIndex + 1)
  Loop Until openingArrowBracketIndex = 0

  'Now we have a string that starts with some text we don't need and some text at the end we don't need
  'But we also have a string with a pattern we can use to place new html tags which can be used to get
  'the text in that way we want
  '
  'The start text will lost automatically. The end text too with a little manipulation before placing all other new tags
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<br><br><br>", "</div>")
  'Now we place the new structure
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<br><strong><br>", "<strong>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<strong><br><br>", "<strong>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<br><br><strong>", "<strong>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<br><br><a name=" & Chr(34) & "_GoBack" & Chr(34) & "></a><strong>", "<strong>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<br><strong>", "<strong>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<strong><br>", "<strong>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<strong>", "</p></div><div><strong>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "</strong>", "</strong><p>")
  htmlString = Replace(htmlString, "<br>", "</p><p>")

  'Our htmlString contains all info we want. So we can
  'use the ie to generate a new dom object
  ie.Quit
  Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate "about:blank"
  Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'First we encapsulate our htmlString in a body tag to be able to query it afterwards
  htmlString = "<body>" & htmlString & "</body>"
  '
  'Than we use a little trick to get the htmlString as dom object
  ie.document.Write (htmlString)
  Set nodeNewBody = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("body")(0)

  'Now we can get the text like we want it
  '
  'The information for every single country is placed now in a div tag
  'By creating a node collection of all div tags we lost automatically
  'the not needed text at the start and at the end
  Set nodeAllDiv = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
  '
  'Place data for each country in the excel table
  For Each nodeOneDiv In nodeAllDiv
    'Get country name
    countryName = Trim(nodeOneDiv.getElementsByTagName("strong")(0).innertext)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(tableRow, tableColumn).Value = countryName
    tableColumn = tableColumn + 1

    'Get date of message
    'The date string is placed allways in the first p tag
    infoDate = Trim(nodeOneDiv.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innertext)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(tableRow, tableColumn).Value = infoDate
    tableColumn = tableColumn + 1

    'Get the message itself
    'The text of the message is placed from p tag 2 till the last p tag
    Set nodeAllP = nodeOneDiv.getElementsByTagName("p")
    '
    For p = 1 To nodeAllP.Length - 1
      infoText = infoText & Trim(nodeAllP(p).innertext) & Chr(10)
    Next p
    '
    'Write Infotext to table without the last new line
    ActiveSheet.Cells(tableRow, tableColumn).Value = Left(infoText, Len(infoText) - 1)
    infoText = ""
    tableColumn = 1
    tableRow = tableRow + 1
  Next nodeOneDiv
  ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much Zwenn for this amazing answer! It worked flawlessly once, but now I get a an error *Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set* This is for line 44: *"Set nodeAllP = nodeTextContainer.getElementsByTagName("p")"*

Comment: The error means that no object *nodeTextContainer* could be created in the line before. This can only happen if there is no HTML element with the CSS class *middle*. But I can't imagine that, because *middle* belongs to the basic page structure. Did you test the macro with another link or with the same one twice?

Comment: I've revised the macro. There was a basic error with nested span tags and some problems with tag patterns I have not seen yesterday. I explained the nested tags problem in the comments of the macro. It works fine for me now. I could not reproduce the error you described.

Comment: Hi @Zwenn, thanks very much for the update! So I disabled Option Explicit and now it works until Papua New Guinea, but then I get *Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument* on one of the last lines of code: *ActiveSheet.Cells(tableRow, tableColumn).Value = Left(infoText, Len(infoText) - 1)*

I'm thinking it could be the HTML code from the webpage that has changed? Could you try now? Thanks again :)

Comment: The revised macro did not work properly just 30 minutes later. It encapsulated 2 countries into 2 others because style information suddenly appeared in BR tags and HTML comments that did not exist before. Very unsightly.  The HTML code of the page is totally unstructured and there seem to be new unforeseen patterns all the time. The problem is, the more you try to take this into account, the more unstable the whole thing becomes. Simply because there are more and more possible combinations of HTML tags. Now I must go to bed. I will look tomorrow if there is a solution.

Comment: Ok @Negarev I have updated the macro code in my answer one more time. The br styles and comments seem (fortunately) to be no longer available. At the moment the code works perfectly. But I don't know how long :-/